# Can you get the good ending without wielding the Holy Sword?

Tags: lost-ruins

I possessed the holy sword, but I kept using the Zweihander on the final boss and triggering dialogue, then, after the bit that calls for the holy sword, where she says "divine weapon", I'm not sure whether she lost her fiery, presumably protective, aura, and therefore was vulnerable to any weapon.

Did my eyes trick me? Could I have gotten the good ending without ever swinging the Holy Sword?

Answer (score 1):

I can't say with absolute certainty that it's impossible, but I'm *pretty sure* I tried it. Using any non-divine weapon should just make her teleport around. I don't think it's even possible to get the bad ending, where she basically just ignores you.

Comment: Thanks! And this is such a rare situation that no one's likely to have caught it on video either.